# Erro de Jquery no Demoiselle com JSF e Primefaces

Tags: jquery, jsf, demoiselle

Uma aplicação Demoiselle usa um botão de upload para cada registro inserido em uma lista. Isto é, em certo momento a página pode contem de 1 a N componentes de upload repetidos de acordo com a quantidade de registros selecionados na página anterior. Por exemplo,

```
ID   / Anexo     / Descricao
 1    Selecione    Mala direta 
 2    Selecione    Protesto 
 3    Selecione    Compilação
...
```

No entanto, ao carregar o primeiro arquivo para upload, recebo o alerta de lentidão de SCRIPT:

> Um script desta página pode estar em execução ou parado de
>   responder. Você pode interrompê-lo agora ou continuar para verificar
>   se ele termina a execução.
>
> Script:
>   http://localhost:8080/sas/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces:23

Quanto temos mais de 9 componentes, parece que o xhtml fica muito lento ao tentar recarregar os demais componentes de upload após o primeiro arquivo enviado.

Seguem os códigos:

xhtml:

```
<p:fileUpload id="fileUploadLink" fileUploadListener="#{cc.attrs.fileUploadListener}" auto="true" customUI="true"
                                                label="#{cc.attrs.label}" disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}" update="#{cc.attrs.update}"
                                                oncomplete="window.clearTimeout(timeoutAjaxStatus);timeoutAjaxStatus=null;statusDialog.hide();" 
                                                styleClass="file_input_hidden"/>
```

web.xml:

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
```

Comment: Você poderia colocar o conteúdo do pom.xml e todo o xhtml e se possível o BC que está fazendo o upload. A principio por ser um erro de javascript pode ser configuração ou versão de alguma biblioteca. Mas preciso desses dados adicionais. Não é descartado também alguma coisa relacionada ao navegador, fez o teste em qual deles? se em vários, quais?

Comment: OK. Cara, fiz uma outra análise do problema e o motivo da lentidão era o "refresh" de todos os elementos do grid, incluindo os botoes de upload "selecione...". Isto era causado pelo update que estava no próprio componente, que tinha o o objetivo de exibir o nome do arquivo que foi submetido. Ocorre que este já é o comportamento padrão do componente upload. Retirando o "update grid" o travamento parou. Obrigado.